# homology of the universal cover of wedge of spheres.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces

What is the integral homology of the universal cover of $X=S^{2}\vee S^1$.
Is $H_{n}(X,\mathbf{Z})$ finitely generated abelian group for any $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal cover is $\Bbb R \vee_{n \in \Bbb Z} S^2$, where you glue on a sphere to every integer. By collapsing the contractible subspace $\Bbb R$ we see that the universal cover is homotopy equivalent to a countable wedge of 2-spheres. In particular its second homology is $\Bbb Z^\infty$ and all higher homology is zero.

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified what you meant by $\Bbb{Z}^{\infty}$. (I think the homology group will be an infinite sum and not an infinite product.)